# Asp.net antiforgery TOKEN implementation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can someone give me a sample code for asp.net antiforgery in angularjs, this is a trivial question thanks anyway

Comment: I think you're getting wrong how StackOverflow works, do your own research, try something (several times) and then ask! it's lazy just ask someone else to do the work for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what exactly is the architecture of your angular app, and how the communication between the app and the server is done, you should probably give more details about that, and maybe add  some code, to help people answer you.

Anyway- if this could help you, this is a angular code, to redirect to a route anytime the http service gets a 401 unauthorized response code:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            'response': function (response) {
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status == 401) {
                    var _q = $q.defer();
                    $location.path('/401');
                    _q.reject();
                    return _q.promise;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }])
}])
```